# Stop Google Mobile Ads SDK transfer private data on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, data-protection, google-mobile-ads

I successfully run ads in my app using the Google Mobile Ads SDK. Therefore I imported the following SDK frameworks into my Xcode project:

- GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
- GoogleMobileAds.framework
- GoogleUtilities.xcframework
- nanopb.xcframework
- PromisesObjC.xcframework
- UserMessagingPlatform.framework

Now I have noticed that when opening the app, various processes are started in the background, although I have **not** even initialized the SDK with:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
```

The following messages appear in the console:

```
<Google>[I-ACS023007] Analytics v.70400000 started
<Google>[I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled
<Google>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
<Google>[I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
<Google>[I-ACS023130] Configuration not found. Using default configuration
```

How can I ensure that my users' data (including the IDFA) is not sent to Google unless I have initialized the SDK? What can I do to increase data protection in my app?

I also don't use Firebase in my Google AdMob account and the setting for collecting user measurements is also deactivated. Basically, I only run non-personalized ads, if the user accepts to watch one. Or could there be another cause?